# FileOutputStream adding extra information when saving

Tags: java, android

I am having an issue when creating a file on my internal memory.  I store my information in SQLite and then when I go to extract the data, and I am extracting it and then writing it using the XMLSerializer.  Well, when I debug the application, the information is correct and accurate on the emulator, but once I put the app on my phone to run, the file is incorrect by having additional information appended to it.

Here is my XMLSerializer file I am using:

```
public class WriteRecordsToXML {


public static String createRecord()
{
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try 
    {   
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        //StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
        //xmlSerializer.setOutput(fileOS, "UTF-8");

        xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);

        xmlSerializer.startTag("", "Boats");

        Boats boats = new Boats();

        for(Boats boat : boats.getBoatList())
        {
            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "boat");
            xmlSerializer.attribute("", "boatId", boat.getBoatID());

            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "showId");
            xmlSerializer.text(boat.getBoatShowID());
            xmlSerializer.endTag("", "showId");

            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "showDate");
            xmlSerializer.text(boat.getShowDate());
            xmlSerializer.endTag("", "showDate");

            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "showLocation");
            xmlSerializer.text(boat.getShowLocation());
            xmlSerializer.endTag("", "showLocation");

            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "personName");
            xmlSerializer.text(boat.getPersonName());
            xmlSerializer.endTag("", "personName");

            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "boatName");
            xmlSerializer.text(boat.getBoatName());
            xmlSerializer.endTag("", "boatName");

            xmlSerializer.startTag("", "boatLength");
            xmlSerializer.text(boat.getBoatLength());
            xmlSerializer.endTag("", "boatLength");

            for(BoatOptions boatOption : BoatOptions.boatOptionList)
            {
                if(boatOption.getBoatID().equals(boat.getBoatID()))
                {
                    xmlSerializer.startTag("", "boatOption");
                    xmlSerializer.text(boatOption.getBoatOption());
                    xmlSerializer.endTag("", "boatOption");
                }
            }

            xmlSerializer.endTag("", "boat");               
        }

        xmlSerializer.endTag("", "Boats");

        xmlSerializer.endDocument();
        xmlSerializer.flush();
        //return writer.toString().getBytes();
    } 
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return writer.toString();
}
```

}

Like I said from above, when I check the writer object it holds my information correctly.

Here is where I am saving the extracted information and I have tried so many different things but nothing is fixing it:

```
public void extractData(View view)
    {
        File file = new File(folder, File.separator + "BoatShow_" + boatShowID + ".xml");
        String fileName = "BoatShow_" + boatShowID + ".xml";

    try {
        if(file.exists())
        {
            file.delete();
        }
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    boolean isExtracted = false;

    FileOutputStream fileOs = null;
    String content = "";

    try {

        Boats.clearBoatList();
        BoatOptions.boatOptionList.clear();
        db.getBoatRecords(boatShowID);
        fileOs = new FileOutputStream(file);
        String xmlFile = WriteRecordsToXML.createRecord();
        fileOs.write(xmlFile.getBytes());
        fileOs.close();

        FileInputStream fileIs = openFileInput(fileName);
        byte[] input = new byte[fileIs.available()];
        while(fileIs.read(input) != -1)
        {
            content += new String(input);
        }

        if(content.equals(xmlFile))
        {
            isExtracted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isExtracted = false;
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_layout);
    dialog.setTitle("Data Extraction");

    Button dialogButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    TextView dialogText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.customTextView);
    if(isExtracted)
    {
        dialogText.setText("Data successfully extracted for Boat Show: " + boatShowID);
    }
    else
    {
        dialogText.setText("Data did not extract for Boat Show: " + boatShowID);
        file.delete();
    }


    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }               
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

For example, if I have 2 records in my DB:

```
1, 2, 1/3/2014, Missouri, Matt, Flat Boat, < 16 Feet, Other
2, 2, 1/3/2014, Missouri, Matt, Yacht, > 60 Feet, Johnson
```

Extracted data should look like this in my file BoatShow_2.xml:

```
1 2 1/3/2014 Missouri Matt Flat Boat
< 16 Feet
Other
    2 2 1/3/2014 Missouri Matt Yacht
    `> 60 Feet Johnson `
```

When I open the file the first boatOption will also be added to the second boat (only when I use the app directly on my phone)

```
2 2 1/3/2014 Missouri Matt Yacht
Other `> 60 Feet Johnson `
```

Comment: Ok, now where is the problem ?

Comment: Okay, silly question: what OS version are you running on the phone vs emulator?

Comment: But is there anything wrong with the *file?* NB As you have a String, it would make more send to use a FileWriter, or indeed to pass a Writer to the serializing routine rather than have it build up the string in memory. You don't need to call createNewFile().

Comment: The version of my phone is 4.1.2 and the emulator I believe is 4.1.   The file is perfect when viewing it.  I tried passing an OutputStreamWriter to my method, but it wouldn't actually write to the file.